# System Information Recognizes iPhone, Xcode/iTunes Does Not

Tags: iphone, itunes, usb, xcode

Following the directions outlined by Apple [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204095#Mac), i can confirm that the system itself recognizes my device, but iTunes and (more importantly) Xcode refuse to. I made sure to update everything i could; and since this is a vanilla install, I can think of no "third-party security software" that would conflict. How does one troubleshoot this?

**Phone Type**: iPhone 6

**macOS version**: 10.12.6

**iOS version**: 10.3.3

**Full Output of `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`**: [here](https://pastebin.com/Qv5dzFK4)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem with the iTunes Helper. Try reinstalling the [latest version of iTunes](https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/), just in case something broke along the way.